# How do you make a button populate a modal for a Mailchimp popup form in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, modal-dialog, mailchimp

I have a Wordpress website and would like to add a Mailchimp modal to sign up for a newsletter.  However, I do not want it to just appear after a given time, which is the only code provided by Mailchimp.  I have search for plugins that will get the job done but was unable to find a solid choice.  I have found some information on Github, but none specific to Wordpress.

So far I have found this code:

```
<!-- This is the HTML element that, when clicked, will cause the popup to appear. -->

<button id="open-popup">Subscribe to our mailing list</button>

<!-- This is what I have tried putting in the header. -->


<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>

<script>
function showMailingPopUp() {
require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.usXX.list-manage.com","uuid":"YOUR_UUID_GOES_HERE","lid":"YOUR_LID_GOES_HERE"}) })
document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
};

document.getElementById("open-popup").onclick = function() {showMailingPopUp()};
</script>
```

I have tried putting the second part of the code in several different areas, including the header and the widget that the button is in, none have worked.  Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

This is the code for my button, the code for this I input directly into a text widget:

```
<button id="open-mc-popup" onclick ="showMailingPopUp(); return false;">Subscribe</button>
```

This next section I put into the Theme's Header.  If you are new to wordpress or do not know how to get there follow these steps.  `Appearance > Editor > Theme Header (header.php)` if the Theme inherits from a parent theme you will have to click the link for that parent first.  Once you are there you can put this code in between the `<head> </head>` section but be careful not to delete any existing code.

```
<!-- This is the Mailchimp Modal. -->

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
  <script>function showMailingPopUp() {
    require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.usXX.list-manage.com","uuid":"YOUR_UUID_HERE",
      "lid":"YOUR_LID_HERE"}) })
    document.cookie = "MCEvilPopupClosed=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
  };</script>
```

Last make sure that you have updated the `"baseUrl" "uuid"` & `"lid"` to match what Mailchimp gives you for a popup form code.  That can be found after selecting one of your Mailchimp lists (on the Mailchimp website) and selecting popup forms and clicking Get Code.